# How to sync a Unity project, git repo between 2 computers?

Tags: git

I'll explain the scenraio:

I have a great **PC**, which I code in C# with the Unity engine in it. I use Git and GitHub as a SourceControl to just keep track on my repo. Apparently... my wife also like to work on that PC remotely to her office from time to time.

I have some time in my hands, and I also stay in home... and I use my **laptop** meanwhile to just refactor my code, without using the Unity engine itself. It required me to do some projects and DLLs changes so it would (almost) compile on my laptop. I stage only the code changes, commit and push them to the same branch which I work on my PC.

So, I have 2 different git configurations on 2 different endpoints for the same repo. This causes issues when I want to Pull information from my PC towards my Laptop, since git yells "you need to clean your workspace", because I do not stage/upload/commit folder/projects changes to the repo. I merely push the code changes for the refactoring. It blocks me from pulling code changes onto the laptop, and I need to manually cut-copy-paste files everytime I want to work on the git branch and listen to changes.

Any smart workarounds for it? I probably miss some git capabilities...
I'm also open to other suggestions for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [**stash**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your local changes (in simple it basically means store a "snapshot" of the current local changes and reset the branch to the latest commit). Then `pull` and then reapply the stash (+ eventually resolve merge conflict).

> Use `git stash` when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the `HEAD` commit.
>
> The modifications stashed away by this command can be listed with `git stash list`, inspected with `git stash show`, and restored (potentially on top of a different commit) with `git stash apply`. Calling `git stash` without any arguments is equivalent to `git stash push`. A stash is by default listed as `"WIP on branchname …​"`, but you can give a more descriptive message on the command line when you create one.

---

The alternative would be to create a commit with your current changes and resolve merge conflicts while pulling. I see and feel why this might be inconvenient, though ;)

Depends on your workflow - in most bigger companies you will not want to lose a day of work in case of hardware failure so the rule is you are forced to make and push a commit latest at the end of the day / whenever you switch device anyway ;)